# Custom Routes: How does one properly add the id inside a custom route with redirection in Ruby/Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a custom route and I need to add the id inside the redirect call inside of the "to:" key-value pair. I've tried regular way:

```
# My Cars
get '/api/cars/profile/:car_id', to: redirect('/cars/profile/:car_id')
```

I've tried interpolation:

```
# My Cars
get '/api/cars/profile/:car_id', to: redirect("/cars/profile/#{car_id}")
```

But still no solution in sight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it with:

```
# My Cars
get '/api/cars/profile/:car_id', to: redirect('/cars/profile/%{car_id}')
```